# WinForms TreeView glitch when expanding

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview, .net-4.5

I've extended WinForms TreeView in C# in order to draw my own text (I'm drawing a shadowed font with black under white) and everything looks okay apart from when I expand a node with a large number of children (by large I'm only talking 20+).  I've tried to capture what happens but it's so quick I've been unsuccessful so I'll try to explain it.

The TreeView has around 15 1st level nodes in it and when I open one of the 20+ children nodes, I get a glitch where it displays the node under the one I've clicked multiple times (looks like the same amount of times as the children nodes that subsequently appear) for an instant and then displays all the child nodes.  It's very frustrating, mostly because I can't find anything online similar to this.

I've set the TreeView to use double buffering but although it covers lots of flicking, it doesn't cover this glitch.

Here's my TreeView class:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Liq.CommonControls.Tree
{
    public partial class LiqTreeView : TreeView
    {
        private Brush backBrush, highlightBrush, blackBrush, textBrush;
        private Font drawFont;

        private const int TVM_SETEXTENDEDSTYLE = 0x1100 + 44;
        private const int TVM_GETEXTENDEDSTYLE = 0x1100 + 45;
        private const int TVS_EX_DOUBLEBUFFER = 0x0004;
        private const int WM_ERASEBKGND = 0x0014;


        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int msg, IntPtr wp, IntPtr lp);

        public LiqTreeView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DrawNode += LiqTreeView_DrawNode;
            BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 105, 105, 105);
            
            backBrush = new SolidBrush(this.BackColor);
            highlightBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.LightGray);
            blackBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
            textBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.WhiteSmoke);
            drawFont = new Font("Arial", 14, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
        }

        protected override void OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e)
        {
            SendMessage(this.Handle, TVM_SETEXTENDEDSTYLE, (IntPtr)TVS_EX_DOUBLEBUFFER, (IntPtr)TVS_EX_DOUBLEBUFFER);
            base.OnHandleCreated(e);
        }

        protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
        {
            if (m.Msg == WM_ERASEBKGND)
            {
                m.Result = IntPtr.Zero;
                return;
            }
            base.WndProc(ref m);
        }
        
        private void LiqTreeView_DrawNode(object sender, DrawTreeNodeEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Bounds.Height < 1 || e.Bounds.Width < 1) return;

            e.DrawDefault = false;

            if (!e.Node.IsVisible)
                return;
            
            if (e.Node.IsSelected)
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(highlightBrush, e.Bounds);

            Rectangle r = e.Bounds;
            StringFormat sf = new StringFormat();
            sf.Alignment = StringAlignment.Near;
            sf.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Near;
            sf.Trimming = StringTrimming.Character;
            
            r.Y -= 2;
            r.X += e.Node.Level * 10;
            TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, e.Node.Text, drawFont, (Rectangle)r, Color.Black, TextFormatFlags.Left|TextFormatFlags.EndEllipsis);

            r.Y -= 1;
            r.X += 1;
            TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, e.Node.Text, drawFont, (Rectangle)r, Color.WhiteSmoke, TextFormatFlags.Left | TextFormatFlags.EndEllipsis);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, a mark down for an initial question?

Comment: Sounds `DrawMode = TreeViewDrawMode.OwnerDrawAll`. 1) You should define that in the ctor. 2) Override the `OnBeforeExpand` and `OnBeforeCollapse` methods and call the `Invalidate()` method from them. 3) You need to override the `OnMouseClick` method to `GetNodeAt(e.Location)` and select it if its not already selected. 4) You might want to comment this `r.Y -= 2;` and | the `TextFormatFlags.VerticalCenter` to center the text vertically. Happy holidays.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I did override OnBeforeExpand and OnBeforeCollapse and added Invalidate as it was something I saw on one of my searches yesterday but it didn't make any difference (and it was definitely called).

Not sure why I'd need to override OnMouseClick yet?  The selection of the nodes works fine (and highlights with my chosen colour in OnwerDraw.  I can't comment the r.Y -= 2, it's that which gives me the shadowed look - I draw black text first, then draw white text over the top slightly to the right and above, it gives a very nice shadowed look

Comment: I see. Maybe you set other relevant properties elsewhere. Through the designer, code.. We just can't see that. Btw, remove `StringFormat sf = new StringFormat();` since its never been used. Btw2, Override the `Dispose` method to dispose of the graphics objects you create in the `ctor`.

Comment: No, there’s nothing else being set, it’s all pretty simple. If I switch my extended TreeView back to just a normal WinForms TreeView, I don’t get the glitch.

Comment: I just tried adding Invalidate() to BeforeExpand and BeforeCollapse again and this time it worked perfectly.  Not sure how it didn't work before but thanks v much dr.null